# Heroku sending outgoing email: IPs in DUL and blocked by Trend micro

Tags: heroku, trend

We currently need some help setting up email sending from one of our Rails apps via our own Microsoft Exchange SMTP server. It seems that the Heroku IPs are blocked by Trend Micro. We are having this message:

"Your email messages have been blocked by the recipient OR by Trend Micro Email Reputation Service. Contact the recipient or his/her administrator using alternate means to resolve the issue"

What can we do in this case, please give us some guidelines.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can get around the requirement to use the exchange server that's blocking you, you can just use one of the [email add-ons on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp). Alternatively, you could maybe use the [Proximo add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo) to get a static external IP address to send emails from, and then make sure that static IP is whitelisted on your exchange server.